# Why can't I install DBD::mysql so I can use it with Maatkit?

Tags: perl, macos, cpan

I'm trying to install [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) following [the maatkit  instructions](http://maatkit.sourceforge.net/doc/maatkit.html#installation). I can't get past having to install DBD::mysql. "Warning: prerequisite DBD::mysql 1 not found."
When I try to install DBD::mysql from cpan, I get very helpful "make had returned bad status, install seems impossible".

Perl is "v5.8.8 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level", the one that came with OS X. I also tried [building](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#INSTALLATION) from source with same result.

Answer (score 5):

We need more of the error message. Most likely, you are missing the MySQL client development files. I don't know how to install these on OSX. Also see [this older post on OSX 10.5.2](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=678893) , in which some other failures with the mysql client libraries are found.

Possibly post this question with more parts of your error message at [perlmonks.org](http://perlmonks.org), if stackoverflow doesn't allow for convenient pasting of your `make` session or rather the last 20 or 10 lines of it.

Some more Googling with `site:perlmonks.org` also finds [this post](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=318334) which has some more details on things to watch out for when installing DBD::MySQL. Depending on how comfortable you feel with the installation, you might want to manually run the tests, supplying a test database and test user or even skip testing the module.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more googling, this worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/include /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::DBD::mysql'
```

press enter a bunch of times, then in your maatkit folder:

```
perl Makefile.PL
sudo make install
```

and you'll find the mk-* programs in /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to [install MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mac-os-x-installation.html) first.  I usually use the [binary packages](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html#macosx-dmg) they provide for OS X.  The packages do include the headers and MySQL client libraries which DBD::MySQL requires.  Once the MySQL package is installed, DBD::MySQL should install without issue.

Comment: there are already two instances of MySQL installed. Maybe that's what confusing DBD::MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my output:

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite DBD::mysql 1 not found.
Writing Makefile for maatkit

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51b, for apple-darwin9.0.0b5 (i686) using readline 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there are in effect DBD::MySQL packages in the [fink](http://finkproject.org/) repositories. For example:

```
ayaz@ayazs-macbook$ fink list | grep -i 'dbd-mysql'
    dbd-mysql-pm586 3.0008-10   Perl5 Database Interface to MySQL
    dbd-mysql-pm588 3.0008-10   Perl5 Database Interface to MySQL
```

Perhaps installing through fink one of those packages may help alleviate your troubles.

Also, and I cannot be certain of this, you may want to install for MySQL-5.x (if you have that version installed) the mysql15-dev and mysql15-shlibs packages. I installed those through fink thus:

```
$ sudo fink --use-binary-dist install mysql15-dev
```